# Need to replace line from one file based on another file in Linux bash shell

Tags: linux, shell

I have two files , one as a template and other as a input file for next command. I have to update my input file based on the values in template

First file looks like as shown below

```
TKTSPEC.2.ASSETATTRID=REVISION&
TKTSPEC.2.REFOBJECTID=31&
TKTSPEC.2.TICKETSPECID=410&
TKTSPEC.2.SECTION=&
TKTSPEC.3.ASSETATTRID=NUM&
TKTSPEC.3.REFOBJECTID=31&
TKTSPEC.3.TICKETSPECID=411&
TKTSPEC.3.SECTION=&
TKTSPEC.4.ASSETATTRID=MPNUM&
TKTSPEC.4.REFOBJECTID=31&
TKTSPEC.4.TICKETSPECID=412&
TKTSPEC.4.SECTION=&
```

My Template file looks like

```
TKTSPEC.2.ASSETATTRID=REVISION&
TKTSPEC.2.TABLEVALUE=5&
TKTSPEC.3.ASSETATTRID=NUM&
TKTSPEC.3.TABLEVALUE=RDPVS&
TKTSPEC.4.ASSETATTRID=MPNUM&
TKTSPEC.4.TABLEVALUE=NEWPROJECT&
```

My Desired output is as follows

```
TKTSPEC.2.ASSETATTRID=REVISION&
TKTSPEC.2.TABLEVALUE=5&
TKTSPEC.2.REFOBJECTID=31&
TKTSPEC.2.TICKETSPECID=410&
TKTSPEC.2.SECTION=&
TKTSPEC.3.ASSETATTRID=NUM&
TKTSPEC.3.TABLEVALUE=RDPVS&
TKTSPEC.3.REFOBJECTID=31&
TKTSPEC.3.TICKETSPECID=411&
TKTSPEC.3.SECTION=&
TKTSPEC.4.ASSETATTRID=MPNUM&
TKTSPEC.4.TABLEVALUE=NEWPROJECT&
TKTSPEC.4.REFOBJECTID=31&
TKTSPEC.4.TICKETSPECID=412&
TKTSPEC.4.SECTION=&
```

I have to check the ASSETATTRID from my first file and then insert a new line with corresponding value from the second file.Second file has value for every assetattrid.
 Can this be acheived using awk or other linux based commands ?

Comment: You can check  this -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15684563/use-awk-to-parse-source-code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way:

```
awk -F. 'NR==FNR{getline x;a[$2$3]=x;next}$2$3 in a{print;print a[$2$3];next}1' templatefile inpfile
```

Comment: thanks Guru, It works... I am trying to understand this one liner.

Comment: @user2190101 : this http://backreference.org/2010/02/10/idiomatic-awk/  helped me a lot to "grok" awk

Comment: Thanks Olivier , It was a good link to kickstart with awk

Answer (score 1):

this oneliner may work for you:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{k=$0;getline;a[k]=$0;next}$0 in a{$0=$0"\n"a[$0]}1' templ input
```